# E-mail adress link doesn't work in HTML/VBA

Tags: html, vba

In the HTML format of my VBA code, i'm having an error when I try to link my email adress. The VBA debbugging stops at `mailto`.

```
"<a href=www.google.com"">www.google.com</a>" & vbNewLine & _
"<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>"
```

Comment: please specify the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your quotes are seeing the mailto as a variable not string try

```
"<a href=""mailto:webmaster@example.com"">Jon Doe</a>"
```